# We need help regarding Fragment navigation issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

We need help regarding Fragment navigation issue

I have **Acitvity1** in which dynamically add the fragmentA and  fragmentA have one button which name **next** , if we press **next** Button then fragmentB is lunched. now when press **Device hardware back Button** then onCreateView called of fragmentA.

Here My Issues is that any how can we resume/ recall fragmentA  in  **onResume state** or **By preventing oncreateView call** or **previous Retain state**

Please Help me friend , really in trouble
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you used FragmentTransaction's replace method but you should use it's add instead.
See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Please post some of your source code, to have a clearer view

Answer (score 0):

You can, using **backstackentry** refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.BackStackEntry.html)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    loadPreviousFragment();
}
```

and

```
private boolean loadPreviousFragment() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++){
        if(fm.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName().equals(FRAGMENT_A )){
            fm.getFragments().get(i).onResume();
            return true;
        }

        if(fm.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName().equals(FRAGMENT_B )){
            fm.getFragments().get(i).onResume();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and when adding fragment just set backstak name

**fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(FRAGMENT_A );**

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you call fragment replace. You have 3 variants:

1. Call fragmentTransaction.add() instead off replace you will have 2 fragments on screen in the same time, first should probably be invisible. Whan you came back to previous fragment there would no onCreateView call.
2. Store reference to first fragment an use it in add method off fragmentTransaction
3. call addToBackStack when add fragmentB on screen